# How to assign customer to a quote?

Tags: php, magento, quote

I have created a custom API for login and addtocart operations. When the user is not logged in and add products to a cart that quote id is saved and when a user logged in using the my API then I want to assign this customer to the quote that I have saved before.The code I have used to assign the customer to the quote is below.

```
$quoteId = '1720';
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$customer->loadByEmail($email);
$quote          =    Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
$quote->assignCustomer($customer);
```

But when this not working.When the customer is get logged in then a new quote is created against the user.But I want the customer to be assigned to the above quote that he has added before logged in.

Comment: You might need to call `save()` on the quote after `assignCustomer()`

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$quoteId = '1720';
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$customer->loadByEmail($email);
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
$quote->setCustomer($customer);
$quote->save();
```

In my tests, cart can't be empty to set a customer.